# Abp project don't run in first time using

Tags: abp

I have just created ABP project and just added migration, update-database.But when I ran project it appear error like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbQrh.png)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

1. Delete your db (created with initial migration)
2. Delete your all migrations.
3. Run `Xxx.DbMigrator` project with `dotnet run`

   - It will create initial migration first than creates your db.

Test it again.